# Does the command running in detached docker container keep running when exited from ssh?

Tags: docker, containers

I have a few docker containers up in the detached mode on a VPS connected via `ssh`.

In one of the containers, through docker's interactive mode (`docker exec -it <containerID> bash`), I have executed a command which takes approximately 27 minutes to finish.

If I disconnect from the `ssh` session, will the detached container keep the executed command up and running within it?

Comment: `ps -x --forest` should show you that your `docker exec` command is a child of your current shell, itself a child of your sshd session. If you kill the session, all its child will be killed as well.

Comment: @Zeitounator why didn't you write this as an answer?

Comment: @Zeitounator what if I run the `docker exec` with `-d`?

Comment: Did you try ? Did you check what your process is a parent of now ? Is it still tied to you sshd session ? What is your conclusion ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to have the command in a bash file, which is inside the docker container which you are running.

Then try the below command through ssh:

```
ssh <<username>>@<ip address>> docker exec -itd awesome_goodall bash  11.sh
```

While running docker exec, use `-d` also. The above command will close the ssh session and the command we have in the bash script will run inside the container

Note:
The 11.sh file is inside the container, which has the command you want to execute.

Comment: thank you @gopirengaraj for adding this alternative. I will give it a try